# Is gravity not a force?

Tags: gravity

When I jump out of a plane and begin to fall and accelerate, I feel no force whatsoever.  When I stand on the earth, I feel only the force of the Earth pushing me outwards.

I contend the accelerating condition is a natural state brought about by a local curvature of space towards the center of mass of the Earth.  We explain it by Newton's law, but I can't see how two separated bodies can exert a force on each other unless the space between is curved.

Comment: What do you say about two electrically charged separated bodies, do they exert a force on each other or not?

Comment: Congrats - you have found a property of General Relativity, i.e., that gravity is geometry. Unfortunately, you're 100 years too late to get any prizes ;)

Comment: @innisfree, just to nitpick, GR is only about 100 years old. And when it was introduced, it was a few years too early to win any prizes.

Comment: "(...)the force of the Earth pushing me outwards." I figure you'd be flying if it were so.

Comment: "What do you say about two electrically charged separated bodies, do they exert a force on each other or not?"  I agree they do of course, my question is how can they feel an attraction at a distance unless space is again curved?

Comment: @BobBishop The force is felt through the exchange of virtual photons.

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have stumbled upon an important property of General Relativity (GR) that

> *gravity is geometry.*

As you say, the gravitational force is not an ordinary force, but a property of space-time. Objects that appear to be under the influence of gravity are in fact in free-fall, simply following the (geodesics of) the curved space-time. You can find out more about this in any GR textbook or online at e.g. [Einstein online](http://www.einstein-online.info/elementary/generalRT/GeomGravity).

I should add, however, that not all forces permit a geometrical interpretation. Gravity is special because the gravitational "charge" is equal to the inertial mass in $F=ma$. An object's path under gravity is independent of any of that object's properties - it is only a property of space-time.

That is not the case for e.g. the electromagnetic force. For that force, an object's behaviour depends on its electric charge.

Comment: So, as stars, planets, black holes move through space, they warp it, then it "flattens" back out as they move on.  How can physicists speak of a flat universe geometry when all this mass is curving it?

Comment: Your first sentence: Yes, nicely summarised by John Wheeler: "Spacetime tells matter how to move; matter tells spacetime how to curve." 

Second sentence: there are two issues here. On arbitrarily small scales, space-time is always flat (precisely, Minkowski). This means that space-time is smooth.

On large scales, the approximate geometry of the Universe is also flat.

Comment: ok, so the approximate geometry is flat.  If a large mass creates an attractive force by warping or compressing space, would a repulsive force be created if something could stretch space or expand it?

Comment: I'm not a GR expert, tbh, but the "something" you describe sounds like a form of so-called "exotic mattter," which curves space-time in an unusual way. There is no evidence for such exotic matter, and it it would violate some (energy) theorems in GR.